# Hibernate Tools: [Classpath]: Could not create JPA based Configuration

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jboss-tools

I have a Java Project that I earlier used with Hibernate's Native API with hibernate.cfg.xml and then later started using Hibernate as a JPA provider using persistence.xml inside the META-INF folder and everything was working fine.

But when I installed the Hibernate Tools and tried configuring it, I keep getting the [Classpath]: Could not create JPA based Configuration error displayed and I am not able to use its HQL tool. But the ping succeeds for JDBC connection, so its connecting to the database alright.

Following are some of the screenshots of the project and the issues I am facing:
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Could somebody help me resolve this issue?

Comment: What it says in Claspath tab? You noted it shows some problem, right?

Comment: @Guillermo: It said "Could not create JPA based configuration". Shown in the first screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

According to the snapshots it seems that you want to configure it for Hibernate 4.0, which doesn't support JPA 2.1, as JPA provider. So I suggest you to check what follows in order to configurate for JPA 2.0.

1. JPA facet of your project is 2.0 (*project's properties > Project Facets*)
2. Check that you `persistence.xml` has the correct version and schema reference; next is how should be the head tag for JPA 2.0

   `<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
   version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">`
3. In the **Classpath** tab of *Edit launch configuration propeties* (like your first snapshot) check your project appears as *User Entries*, if it doesn't select *User Entries* and then *Add Project* button will be avaible to add your project.

Comment: Yep, I've got all of the 3 points ticked. I've got project facet with 2.0, using version 2.0 in the persistence.xml and have got the project added in the classpath as well. Still the issue remains.

Comment: In point 2 it is not just the version attribute, also should have the correct schema *persistence_2_0.xsd* location. I can easy reproduce the problem mixing wrong configuration in the `persitence.xml` head tag.

Comment: Yep, I've got the correct persistence_2_0 schema working fine for the project. It couldn't be the issue that's causing the issue.